# FLUID templating - nested var

Tags: typo3, fluid, fluid-layout

In a TYPO3 project, I have an array in my fluid template :

```
{subfamilies} [
    france = Paris
    germany = Berlin
    united_kingdom = London
    spain = Madrid
    usa = New York
]
```

It works perfectly but I need to access specific items via the key.
I get the key inside a variable 'my_key' ( == 'france' )
Below is what I already tried :

```
{subfamilies.{my_key}}
{subfamilies."{my_key}"}
{subfamilies.'{my_key}'}
{subfamilies.{{my_key}}}
```

It doesn't work. I tried a lot of solutions.. with no effect.

Any idea ?

Comment: What TYPO3 version do you use? This is possible [since TYPO3v8](https://github.com/TYPO3/Fluid/blob/c73ee75275eb5e4db7f158df03116fd594f33dde/examples/Resources/Private/Singles/Variables.html#L23).

Comment: Hello @MathiasBrodala , i'm using Typo3 6.2

Answer (score 0):

Given that you use TYPO3 6.2 the only option you have is using the [`v:variable.get` viewhelper of the VHS extension](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/2.4.0/Variable/GetViewHelper.html):

```
<v:variable.get name="subfamilies.{my_key}" />
```

In TYPO3v8 and newer the following works out of the box:

```
{subfamilies.{my_key}}
```